# Heading Elements in UIKit HTML Editor

Tags: javascript, uikit, html-editor, html-heading

I looked through the code and it seems like the only ones supported are:

[ 'bold', 'italic', 'strike', 'link', 'image', 'blockquote', 'listUl', 'listOl' ]

To add buttons for heading (H1, H2, H3, etc), do I have to modify the source code? Is there any reason why UIKit is providing such a small list of options?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure that a heading should be a button.  For me, a heading is a text element letting the reader know what the subsequent text contains.  The various headings on a page are effectively a Table of Contents.  On the other hand, a button would be used to indicate to the user that a action can be taken.  Personally I think uikit have their 'limited' options correct.

Comment: But because of that restriction, I can't use the library so what good is that? Besides, the widget is too buggy for a more complex case since it doesn't properly track the structure making HTML invalid. I ended up having to use CKEditor instead.